# Require password on anonymous checkout

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ubercart

I configured ubercart to permit anonymous checkout. 
The problem is in the case mail from the server are blocked by antispam software.
If the password is automatically generated, the customer will never receive it and can't track the order status, so i want to require the password and not only to allow it.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is relatively simple.
In a new module, to define a function like the following:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id=="uc_cart_checkout_form"){
    $form['panes']['customer']["new_account"]['pass']["#required"]=true;
    $form['panes']['customer']["new_account"]['pass_confirm']["#required"]=true;
  }
}
```

eventually in a try - catch block to prevent notices if you will change the configuration in future.